# FCM Notification Icon not changing

Tags: java, android, firebase

Why the hell does it keep displaying the default icon when I already changed the icon that should be displayed in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".FirebaseInitializer"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".TitleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

My messaging service class extending FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void createNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TitleActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri notifSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Solitude")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSound(notifSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This is so frustrating. Kindly please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest meta-data defines `ic_launcher` and your java code defines `ic_launcher` too.
Where exactly should a different icon appear? Or in other words: Exactly, which icon do you expect?

Also, make sure you send a message with a `data { ... }` part, otherwise your service doesn't get called if the app is in background.
In this case, pure notification pushes are drawn by the system.

Next thing is, that it depends on the Android version, what happens. Since (I think) Android 7, notification icons should be monochrome, so your `ic_launcher` is very likely not qualified to be a notification icon.
You should design your own notification icon that is only white pixels with alpha.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers Gris

Comment: ic_launcher is the same pic logo which I made by New Image Asset. What if my app is not running in background and foreground, can I use a custom notif icon? What do you mean by white pixels with alpha? Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Use this

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

not use this

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);